# Comparing a string-date with another string-date in MySql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I'm trying to get entries from MySql server where the dates are `> date_begin and < date_end`

My problem is that the table column "`date`" is set to `VARCHAR`, and the string I am comparing it is also directly from an `<input type="text"/>`

The date format ( as string / varchar ) in the mysql table and in the textbox will be `DD.MM.YYYY`

my problem is that if i do

( php code )

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE date>='" . $dateBegin . "' AND date<='" . $dateEnd . "'";
```

the result will be completely random.

I know why this happening so the question is: How can I compare this to get the right result ?

thank you all who can help

**UPDATE :**

Now I've tryed this solution, but it also doesn't work.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM artikel WHERE STR_TO_DATE(datum, '%d.%m.%Y')>=STR_TO_DATE('" . $_REQUEST['dateTo'] . "', '%d.%m.%Y')" . "' AND STR_TO_DATE(datum, '%d.%m.%Y')<=STR_TO_DATE('" . $_REQUEST['dateTo'] . "', '%d.%m.%Y')";
```

the `$_REQUEST['dateFrom']` and `$_REQUEST['dateTo']` came from 2 textboxes and the input is a string like this `"05.06.2005"`.

in the db-table 'artikel' (german for articles) in the column 'datum' (german for date) the values are VARCHAR's with the same format ( "05.06.2005" ).

Comment: Why date is varchar ? why not timestamp or Datetime ?

Comment: Keeping a date as a string, and then processing it as a date, means that you create additional coding overheads, additional load on the server, use additional disc space on the server, introduce the possibility of 'dates' with incorrect formatting, and destroy the ability of the SQL Engine to use indexes to search that field. *[I can't over-emphasise this too strongly]*: Store data in the correct data-type, don't store strings and convert them 'on the fly'; you're headed for a world of hurt, inefficiencies, and debugging hell.

Comment: it's not my mysql server, if i would have the ability of changing the datatype to "date" i proppably would. i'm just the guy who has to add a filter function to an existing web-application. but thanks anyway

Comment: The you have my sympathy, I'm all to used to the My-Hands-Are-Tied type of pain.  May the Lord have mercy on your soul.

Answer (score 9):

Always compare dates with dates, integers with integers etc.

With MySQL you can use the `str_to_date` functions to specify how your string-date is to be processed.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

e.g. if your date column is called "mydate":-

```
SELECT * from table
where STR_TO_DATE(mydate, '%m/%d/%Y') >= STR_TO_DATE('04/31/2004', '%m/%d/%Y')
...
```

And always ensure you're validating any string input from the user to avoid SQL injection attacks.

**EDIT**: as Dems points out above, this is suboptimal as a date value should be stored as date value in the database.

Comment: i'll try this. is this STR_TO_DATE(date, '%m/%d/%Y') a valid MYSQL function ?

Comment: @Ace: yes. See the link I pasted in to the answer.

Comment: @Ace: you would put your "$dateBegin" in place of the "4/31/2004" etc.

Comment: so the first attribute is the actual "string-date" and the second attribute is the format ? hab i use dots "." instead of "/" ?

Comment: ok thank you, is there another method to compare with Prices like 15,39 or 15.39 ? i would be glad if you could post that as edit in your answer.

Comment: also to your current edit: i dont have acess to the database, if i would, i proppably would have structured the whole database in a better way ^^ and again, is there a similar function in mySQl to deal with Prices ( something like STR_TO_DOUBLE("16,95") ?

Comment: @Ace: not that I know of - you may have to resort to using REPLACE or some regex logic.

Comment: i've saw that there is a CAST() function , can't i use this > WHERE prise<=CAST( "13,90" AS DECIMAL) ??

Comment: well now i've tryed the solution but it seems not to work. see my update. did i do something wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use between

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE date between'" . $dateBegin . " AND " . $dateEnd . "'";
```

Comment: the problem is that MYSQL can't compare dates as string.